# Efficient approach for recursive functions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have given three recursion functions `fun1(int )`, `fun2(int )`, `fun3(int)`. All three function depends on each other i.e.

```
fun1(m) = a * fun2(m-1) - b * fun3(m-1)
fun2(m) = c * fun1(m-1) - d * fun3(m-1)
fun3(m) = e * fun1(m-1) + f * fun2(m-1)
```

I have to find value for any of these function. How to do it efficiently(in terms of time complexity and non-recursion approach)?

Comment: Such function descriptions are incomplete: you need a value for which the functions result is known.

Comment: Actually afun2(m-1) is a* fun2(m-1) and same for other functions. While typing question * got removed automatically. Also Assuming fun1(0)=fun2(0)=fun3(0)=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can express your three equations as a matrix multiply:

```
[f1(m)] = [0 a -b] [f1(m-1)]
[f2(m)] = [c 0 -d] [f2(m-1)]
[f3(m)] = [e f  0] [f3(m-1)]
```

Then:

```
[f1(m)] = [0 a -b]^m [f1(0)]
[f2(m)] = [c 0 -d]   [f2(0)]
[f3(m)] = [e f  0]   [f3(0)]
```

So assuming you know the values of f1(0), f2(0), f3(0), you can compute the values for f1(m), f2(m) and f3(m) in O(log m) arithmetic operations by computing the matrix power using exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: This throws a `SquareBracketsMissingException`.

Answer (score -1):

If your coefficients a,b,c,d,e,f don't depend on m, but are absolute constants (or even arbitrary polynomials in variable not depending on m), then the recurrence you describe is called 'linear'. Such case is completely solved by [Petkovšek's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petkov%C5%A1ek's_algorithm).

The algorithm basically lets one compute a so-called closed form of the recurrence. It is described in detail here: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html